# Get custom fields without _edit_last, _edit_lock, _wp_page_template and _visual-subtitle

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, post-meta

I'm getting custom fields using

`<?php $meta = get_post_custom($level_2->ID); ?>
<?php foreach ( $meta as $key => $value) { ?>
  <?php echo $key.': '.$value[0].'<br />'; ?>
<?php } ?>`

and it is showing

`_edit_last: 1<br>
_edit_lock: 1483226440:1<br>
_wp_page_template: page-services.php<br>
Body Repair: ValueBodyRepair<br>
_visual-subtitle: <br>`

I need only 4th row `Body Repair: ValueBodyRepair<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would adjust the code this way, you would get only the one you need:

```
<?php $meta = get_post_custom($level_2->ID); ?>
<?php foreach ( $meta as $key => $value) { ?>
  <?php if(substr($key, 0, 1) !== '_'): ?>
    <?php echo $key.': '.$value[0].'<br />'; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I was looking for.